# Access to nginx stream proxy is not logged in access_log file

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, access-log

Thanks for checking my question.

I'm trying to log user access from browser, into access_log file which is not working now.

My system :

[User]-[TCP proxy]-[webserver]

nginx/1.6 in AWS EC2

nginx configuration :

```
load_module '/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so';
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

stream {
    log_format basic '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
                     '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                     '$session_time';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log basic;

    server {
        listen 80;
        proxy_pass web.server.com:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass web.server.com:443;
    }
}
```

I opened the website from my local laptop through proxy server with Chrome, it opens well and the chrome devtool shows proxy server's ip in `Headers tab > General > Remote Address field`.
I checked dig from my laptop and it indicated proxy server's ip,
even tcpdump in proxy server showed good logs : `sudo tcpdump -nn -A -s1500 -l -i eth0 port 443`

```
(from tcpdump)
23:51:46.944945 IP user_ip.27149 > proxy_ip: length 357
23:51:46.945040 IP proxy_ip.44488 > webserver_ip.443: length 357
23:51:47.026161 IP webserver_ip.443 > proxy_ip.44488: length 364
23:51:47.026245 IP proxy_ip.443 > user_ip.27149: length 364
```

But when I opened the access log file in the proxy server there were no entries.

Unlike the similar question in stackoverflow [Nginx access logs entries don't get created for some connections when they happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817791/nginx-access-logs-entries-dont-get-created-for-some-connections-when-they-happe)
, there was no initial entry. just empty.

I suspect access_log config at first, but when I curl the same url from my laptop, entries suddenly appear in access_log file. It appears every time I curl the url.

```
user_ip [15/Feb/2021:23:21:25 +0000] TCP 200 1291080 3279 356.730
user_ip [15/Feb/2021:23:28:24 +0000] TCP 200 215 568 119.923
user_ip [15/Feb/2021:23:33:24 +0000] TCP 200 5646 643 300.140
```

I'm not sure why only curl requests were logged into the access_log file.

All requests were made on the https protocol.

Comment: Have you a tried a different file?  Maybe it's not happy with two writers to the same file.

Comment: @AllanWind l changed the access.log file name to access1.log for 80, access2.log for 433, put each access_log setting into each server block then retired.
But I still can't find access log from chrome, from both files.  thanks for the idea.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but a working config might be a step forward https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083611/how-to-make-nginx-print-full-log-for-tcp-stream. If new access log was created, that rules out permissions, otherwise you could try to log to syslog with `access_log syslog:unix:/dev/log`.  Finally, my advise is to move this question to serverfault as it's not a programming question.

Comment: @AllanWind I see. thanks for the hint. let me try. 
I'll move this question to serverfault as well.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the question to serverfault.

https://serverfault.com/questions/1053914/access-to-nginx-stream-proxy-is-not-logged-in-access-log-file